# Is it okay to pass an object to a new object constructor and not use it inside?

Tags: java

Is it okay to pass an object type, or simply a type of any kind into the constructor of a new object then not use it inside of the constructor?

The purpose is to have the new object be created based on what parent class it resides in (it is aggregated) so it generates different variables for itself based on that fact.

Or is there a better way to do this?

```
public class ObjectA {

    private MalleableObject obj;

    public void createObject(){
        obj = new MalleableObject(this);
    }
}

public class ObjectB {

    private MalleableObject obj;

    public void createObject(){
        obj = new MalleableObject(this);
    }
}

public class MalleableObject{

    private boolean doIBelongToA;

    public MalleableObject(ObjectB obj){
        doIBelongToA = false;
    }

    public MalleableObject(ObjectA obj){
        doIBelongToA = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: in this specific case, why not pass the boolean directly instead of the class? In a more generic case, if you're not using the object, why not pass the condition parameter or the object you're actually using in the controller?

Comment: This is valid. Now, is there a better way of doing hat you want to achieve (which you didn't tell us), probably.

Comment: I would say this is bad practice since it is confusing for anyone trying to understand the code.

Comment: it is possible, but it might lead to issues. any failure further down the road when that instance is used, the one using it might think he has passed an invalid param, while the param itself is pointless.

Comment: As my own idea that just sparked, I could also make ObjectA and ObjectB be derived from a common interface, pass the interface type as the parameter, and inside the constructor of MalleableObject, I'd check whether the Object is an instance of A or B, and set default values based on that. Would that be better?

Comment: @TiboroJacko: You better not edit an answer to add your comment. Use comments area against each of the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you are taking will definitely work, But the question is whether it is a good idea or not, The answer is depends on the use case that  you are trying to tackle.

**You asked about taking a object as parameter in constructor and not using it**

If you are not using the property of passed parameter then why to take that in parameter, for that we have empty constructor , even when you don't specify it is by default injected

```
 public MalleableObject(ObjectB obj){
    doIBelongToA = false; // if you are directly setting the value without 
    //using obj b then use default constructor.
 }

public MalleableObject(ObjectA obj){
    doIBelongToA = true;
}

/*If you are interested in setting the value based on the reference only there 
  is no problem with your approach as well, One alternative you can take to 
  combine both of them in single constructor and check the reference and set 
  the value accordingly*/
```

If you use the property of the object for creating new object then certainly it's a good idea,

> Copy constructor if you are using same object as parameter, Prototype design pattern if you are creating your object with similiar object already created

The example that you gave is a very basic example which does not highlight any use case and hence the approach you have taken will not be suggested

Answer (score 1):

The simpler approach would be just adding the boolean variable in the constructor of MalleableObject.

```
public class ObjectA {
  private MalleableObject obj;
  public void createObject(){
    obj = new MalleableObject(true);
  }
}

public class ObjectB {
  private MalleableObject obj;
  public void createObject(){
    obj = new MalleableObject(false);
  }
}

public class MalleableObject{
  private boolean doIBelongToA;
  public MalleableObject(boolean doIBelongToA){
    this.doIBelongToA = doIBelongToA;
  }
}
```

This would easily assure that the object made from class A has value true for doIBelongToA.
Also, you will not have to add different constructors for further classes, if added, ensuring extensibility

Comment: This is the obvious way of handling but the question is more about whether it is a better idea or not

Comment: The question also asks about a better way to do it

Comment: You should comment about the problem with the current approach then describe better approach and please include code snippet how the constructor can actually be called based upon the reference of the object

Answer (score 0):

While you aren't using it directly, you are definitely using information from the parameter. Personally, I'd save the reference, or at least its type, for later use in case you need it and implement `doIBelongToA` as a method, but there's nothing technically wrong with your approach:

```
public class MalleableObject{
    private Class ownerType;

    public MalleableObject(Class ownerType) {
        this.ownerType = ownerType;
    }

    public boolean doBelongToA() {
        return ownerType.equals(ObjectA.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing `Class` equals checking will easy fall into problem of violation of Liskov Substitution principle.  A *slightly* better choice may be `ObjectA.class.isAssignableFrom(ownerType)`

Answer (score 0):

The above approach works but it's not a best practice and hence has some limitations. I would suggest you use builder pattern where you can create use of a builder to create an object and then have a method that defines the behavior. You will be able to extend this to add variables/business logic in the future.

I think the Factory pattern is also good
 thing to look at

Comment: How builder pattern can be a fit for this use case?, Factory pattern can be explored for this but this is no where near to the solution for the question asked, It would be even better to give some code snippet explaining your point